# Find value in column and change cell to left with an if statment

Tags: vba, if-statement

This VBA script should take the value in the cell A37 and check if its in the C column of another worksheet. When the number is found the column to the left should be changed to 0. If it is already 0 then a message box will inform the user and if the number does not exist another message box will inform them of this.
This is the VBA I am using to accomplish this. However, every time I try to run it there is a "compile error: Next without For"

**Update** This issue now is that I need to activate the cell that the fcell is in before doing an Active.cell offset

```
Sub Cancelled()

Dim x As Long
Dim regRange As Range
Dim fcell As Range
x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Welcome").Range("A37").Value
Set regRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Registration").Range("C:C")
For Each fcell In regRange.Cells
    If fcell.Value = x Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
        If ActiveCell.Value = 1 Then
            ActiveCell.Value = 0
            MsgBox "Changed to zero"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            MsgBox "That registration number is already cancelled"
            Exit Sub
        End If 
    End If
Next fcell
    MsgBox "That number does not exist"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit for new question: No need to use `Select` and `ActiveCell`

```
If fcell.Value = x Then
    If fcell.Offset(0,-1).Value = 1 Then
        fcell.Offset(0,-1).Value = 0
        ...
```

Edit 2: A further suggestion: You could also use the `Range.Find` method. This will throw an error if nothing is found so you have to catch that:

```
On Error Resume Next 'If an error occurs, continue with the next line
Set fcell = regRange.Find(x)
On Error GoTo 0 'disable the error handler
If fcell Is Nothing Then 'If Find failed
    MsgBox "That number does not exist"
Else
    'do your stuff with fcell here
End If
```

Comment: Thanks...slight over sight I was trying different things and the End If didnt make it into this script. I still get a Error 1004: application defined or object defined error.

Comment: Please edit your question with the new error message and the line it appears on

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is not too late to answer your question:

```
Sub Cancelled()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim regRange As Range
    Dim fcell As Range
    x = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Welcome").Range("A7").Value
    Set regRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Registration").Range("C:C")
    For Each fcell In regRange.Cells
        If fcell.Value = x Then
            If fcell.Offset(0, -1).Value = 1 Then
                fcell.Offset(0, -1).Value = 0
                MsgBox "Changed to zero"
            Else
                MsgBox "That registration number is already cancelled"
            End If
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next fcell
    MsgBox "That number does not exist"
End Sub
```

Instead of

```
Set regRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Registration").Range("C:C")
```

its better to get the last row in `Column C` and then set your range as:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Registration").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Set regRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Registration").Range("C1:C" & lastRow)
```